# Call Main activity from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, native

[fragment class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2kYG.png)
[Home/main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2jLu.png)
How to limit my main activity to not go back on the last page of my Fragment once return from the last page of Fragment to Main activity like I have One Home activity and that home activity leads to 3 more activities on clicking the button and in which one activity has fragments. The last page of the fragment is leading to home activity but when I back pressed on the home activity it again leads me to the last page of a fragment from where I've come and then I press the back button again then my application shuts

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question is rather hard to understand and seems a little confused; you may need to break it up a bit and clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding your `Fragments` to the `FragmentManager` make sure to avoid adding it to the `backstack`, if you don't want it to appear on its own.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout,fragment);
//Adding null will stop the fragment from reappearing on a backpress.
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);          
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In the future please post code in text format. Do not post images of code. If you need to show some view behavior on the screen then its fine to post images, but not code.